# Javascript getter using defineProperty for String returns null

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to define a simple getter for `String` object in Javascript. I used to do the following:
`String.prototype.__defineGetter__("lowerCase", function() { return this.toLowerCase(); });`

So, `'EXAMPLE'.lower` would return `'example'`.

However the `__defineGetter__` method is depreacted. I tried to do:

```
Object.defineProperty(String, "lower", {
  get: function () {
    return this.toLowerCase();
  }
});
```

But, `'EXAMPLE'.lower` will be `null` this way.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Write property to prototype `Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "lower", {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.prototype` instead of `String`. The way you are doing it, it will return `String.toLowerCase()`, which does not make sense. The getter must be defined on the prototype, not on the class, like you did in your first attempt with `__defineGetter__`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the first line

```
Object.defineProperty(String, "lower", {
```

by

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "lower", { //notice that you are making a change in prototype rather than String directly.
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- You should define the getter on the prototype
- If you plan to write `'EXAMPLE'.lower()` with the parentheses, then the getter should not call the `toLowerCase` function, but return a reference to that function, since the calling part happens when you do `.lower()`:

```js
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "lower", {
  get: function () {
    return this.toLowerCase;
  }
});

console.log('EXAMPLE'.lower());
```

#### Alternative for when executing `toLowerCase` in the getter:

You should in total call the function `toLowerCase` just once. If you are planning to write `'EXAMPLE'.lower()`, then those parentheses mean you call it there, so then you should not *also* call it in your getter. If you would do that, the getter would return the result string, and applying `()` to that will return an error. At that moment `lower` is not a method, but a non-function property.

So you could define `lower` as a non-function property, and then you should not call it like a function. So this also works:

```js
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "lower", {
  get: function () {
    return this.toLowerCase(); // <-- call it here
  }
});

console.log('EXAMPLE'.lower); // <-- but then don't call it here!
```

Note that in both solutions the parentheses occur only once -- i.e. the place where you call `toLowerCase`. Having them twice makes no sense.

Comment: why the reference to function ? any specific reason ?

Comment: I added an explanation for that to my answer. But in short: you can have it both ways.

Comment: Reading the question again, I might have been stressing a point that the OP did not have a problem with in the first place. ;-)

Comment: That's true, I actually use the method in your 'alternative' answer in my codes. I call the function inside the getter. I know doing `(function()) ()` wrong! In my original post, I only missed the `prototype` part of the String object. Anyways, thanks for this great explanation. :)